# Why is there a 200ms gap between onload and domcontentloaded?

Tags: html, performance, firebug, onload

i am experiencing a huge gab between the documentloaded and the onload event. Firebug net pannel tells me, that all of the content has been already loaded way before the onloadevent triggers. What is causing this gap and what can I do to close it? The document validates against html 4.01 transitional and has been served with disabled browser cache.

The screenshot of the timeline in firebug on firefox 4.0.1
[image: firebug onload event]

Thank you for any hint on how to solve that.

Here is the code of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>  
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>demo</title> 
<base href="http://snake.demo_de/">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="de">
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 800">
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="YlTcF8Ni3pAtunRAjFrOtCkzjkoeaiv3U-zgsOMWKT4"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/g/p/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/g/p/IC_iph.png">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app_global/dsp_layout.min.css?1307341134">
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app_global/dsp_layout_fixIE6.css?1306831142">
<![endif]-->  

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="http://snake.demo_de/subapp_rss/new-classifieds.xml">

</head>
<body onload="" onunload="">
<a name="top"></a>
<div id="pagewidth" >
<div id="header" >
<a id="logo" href="http://snake.demo_de">
<img src="/g/p/BG_lg_de.gif" alt="demo" title="demo Kleinanzeigenmarkt Startseite" style="width:94px; height:40px">
</a>
<div id="search" >

<form id="search-form" action="/subapp_search/search.php" method="get" name="search">
<input type="text" name="q" id="fq"  value="" maxlength="35" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="at" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="df" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="pf" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="catid" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="pb" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="pe" value="">
<input type="submit" value="suchen" id="go">
</form> 
<ul id="search-autocomplete"><li></li></ul>

        </div>

<a id="post-classified" href="/kostenlos-inserieren.htm">Kostenlos inserieren</a>

<ul id="topnavi">
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kostenfrei-registrieren.htm" title="Mehr Mökeiten als Mitglied" rel="nofollow" onclick="shouldShowUnloadInfo = false;">Registrieren</a></li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kostenfrei-anmelden.htm" title="Mehr Möglichkeiten als Mitglied" rel="nofollow" onclick="shouldShowUnloadInfo = false;">Anmelden</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
<p></p>

<h1 class="listtitle" style="display:inline;">Kostenlose Kleinanzeigen Deutschland. Günstige Angebote finden oder selbst kostenlos inserieren.</h1>
<p></p>
<table width="772" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-bottom:15px" border="0">
<tr valign="top">

<td width="163" height="120">
<a href="/kleinanzeige/fewo-und-fezi-im-ostseeheilbad-zingst-magdeburg" title="FeWo und FeZi im Ostseeheilbad Zingst"><img src="/data/adpix/thumb/fewo-und-fezi-im-ostseeheilbad-zingst-549.jpg" width="120" height="90" alt="FeWo und FeZi im Ostseeheilbad Zingst"  border="0"></a>
<br>

<a href="/kleinanzeige/fewo-und-fezi-im-ostseeheilbad-zingst-magdeburg" title="FeWo und FeZi im Ostseeheilbad Zingst">FeWo und FeZi im.</a><br>
Magdeburg&nbsp;70&euro;
</td>

<td width="163" height="120">
<a href="/kleinanzeige/die-zukunft-selbst-in-die-hand-nehmen-saarbruecken" title="Die Zukunft selbst in die Hand nehmen!"><img src="/data/adpix/thumb/die-zukunft-selbst-in-die-hand-nehmen-383376-0.jpg" width="120" height="90" alt="Die Zukunft selbst in die Hand nehmen!"  border="0"></a>
<br>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/die-zukunft-selbst-in-die-hand-nehmen-saarbruecken" title="Die Zukunft selbst in die Hand nehmen!">Die Zukunft selbs.</a><br>

Saarbrücken
</td>

<td width="163" height="120">
<a href="/kleinanzeige/diese-lage-ist-einzigartig-oy-mittelberg" title="Diese Lage ist einzigartig!"><img src="/data/adpix/thumb/diese-lage-ist-einzigartig-438066-0.jpg" width="120" height="90" alt="Diese Lage ist einzigartig!"  border="0"></a>
<br>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/diese-lage-ist-einzigartig-oy-mittelberg" title="Diese Lage ist einzigartig!">Diese Lage ist ei.</a><br>
Oy-Mittelberg
</td>

<td width="163" height="120">

<a href="/kleinanzeige/2-3-familienhaus-mit-2-einzelgaragen-darmstadt" title="2-3 Familienhaus mit 2 Einzelgaragen"><img src="/data/adpix/thumb/2-3-familienhaus-mit-2-einzelgaragen-416016-0.jpg" width="120" height="90" alt="2-3 Familienhaus mit 2 Einzelgaragen"  border="0"></a>
<br>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/2-3-familienhaus-mit-2-einzelgaragen-darmstadt" title="2-3 Familienhaus mit 2 Einzelgaragen">2-3 Familienhaus.</a><br>
Darmstadt&nbsp;425.000&euro;
</td>

<td width="163" height="120">
<a href="/kleinanzeige/ein-bis-zweifamilienhaus-in-zentraler-lage-von-landshut-landshut" title="Ein bis Zweifamilienhaus in zentraler Lage von Landshut!"><img src="/data/adpix/thumb/ein-bis-zweifamilienhaus-in-zentraler-lage-von-landshut-415409-0.jpg" width="120" height="90" alt="Ein bis Zweifamilienhaus in zentraler Lage von Landshut!"  border="0"></a>

<br>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/ein-bis-zweifamilienhaus-in-zentraler-lage-von-landshut-landshut" title="Ein bis Zweifamilienhaus in zentraler Lage von Landshut!">Ein bis Zweifamil.</a><br>
Landshut&nbsp;195.000&euro;
</td>
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="772" border="0">
<tr>

<td valign="top" width="180" style="//border-left: 1px solid #F0ECDB;">

<p class="heading">Willkommen bei demo</p>
<ul id="advantages_fx" >
<li><span class="sprites-1 sprite-IC_vf_1"></span>Kostenlos inserieren</li>
<li><span class="sprites-1 sprite-IC_vf_1"></span>Keine Verkaufsgebühren</li>
<li><span class="sprites-1 sprite-IC_vf_1"></span>Über 500.000 Besucher</li>

<li><span class="sprites-1 sprite-IC_vf_1"></span>Geprüfte Kleinanzeigen</li>
</ul>

<div class="wrapper">
<h2>Regionale Anzeigen</h2><br>

<img name="KarteDE150px" class="map"  src="/g/p/Karte-DE-150-map.png" width="150" height="203" border="0" id="KarteDE150px" usemap="#m_KarteDE150px" alt=""><map name="m_KarteDE150px" id="m_KarteDE150px">
<area shape="poly" coords="125,63,127,69,117,70,117,63,125,63,125,63" href="http://berlin.demo_de/"title="Berlin" alt="Berlin" >
<area shape="poly" coords="57,33,61,40,67,42,74,43,82,46,86,50,91,54,88,56,84,56,79,59,84,74,82,78,77,79,78,91,74,91,63,97,62,91,60,89,58,89,54,79,51,73,52,70,52,68,49,70,46,68,45,67,41,70,43,72,43,77,35,77,34,71,30,68,26,69,24,73,21,73,21,67,16,67,18,63,21,62,25,49,22,41,23,39,24,37,27,36,33,36,36,37,37,39,37,43,40,45,41,42,42,39,46,42,47,40,46,38,45,36,45,33,47,33,52,33,57,33,57,33" href="http://niedersachsen.demo_de/" title="Niedersachsen" alt="Niedersachsen" >
<area shape="poly" coords="71,40,73,44,64,44,64,38,72,37,71,40,71,40" href="http://hamburg.demo_de/"  title="Hamburg" alt="Hamburg" >

<area shape="poly" coords="58,8,59,7,61,6,64,6,65,9,67,12,65,17,68,17,69,18,70,20,70,18,73,18,78,21,83,19,83,24,78,27,79,30,79,33,80,35,82,37,76,45,72,42,71,39,70,35,66,37,63,39,60,36,57,33,54,31,51,30,53,27,49,20,51,17,53,15,51,12,49,10,49,6,58,8,58,8" href="http://schleswigholstein.demo_de/" title="Schleswig-Holstein" alt="Schleswig-Holstein" >
<area shape="poly" coords="113,19,120,24,123,25,127,31,129,33,133,34,134,41,131,42,127,39,120,44,113,49,101,45,89,51,85,48,83,46,78,45,82,38,80,35,79,33,81,30,84,29,86,30,88,31,91,28,93,25,102,21,110,19,113,19,113,19" href="http://mecpom.demo_de/" title="Mecklenburg-Vorpommern" alt="Mecklenburg-Vorpommern" >
<area shape="poly" coords="119,94,127,96,131,95,134,93,136,90,141,90,146,92,149,97,146,108,142,103,137,103,139,107,126,111,116,119,109,121,105,125,100,122,100,119,100,117,106,115,104,113,111,108,103,101,103,97,103,92,105,90,113,90,117,90,119,91,119,94,119,94" href="http://sachsen.demo_de/"  title="Sachsen" alt="Sachsen" >
<area shape="poly" coords="103,59,101,65,102,67,103,68,102,72,103,75,108,79,115,81,117,83,119,87,103,91,102,96,105,106,103,107,97,105,91,101,92,99,91,96,86,96,83,93,78,88,78,79,84,79,85,74,80,59,93,55,103,59,103,59" href="http://sachsenanhalt.demo_de/" title="Sachsen-Anhalt" alt="Sachsen-Anhalt" >
<area shape="poly" coords="21,143,23,149,22,151,22,153,19,154,10,149,10,146,11,142,16,142,21,143,21,143" href="http://saarland.demo_de/" title="Saarland" alt="Saarland" >
<area shape="poly" coords="36,116,34,120,34,122,36,124,30,131,33,132,38,132,41,138,40,139,39,141,40,144,42,148,38,158,35,158,27,155,21,145,19,142,16,141,9,144,7,143,10,137,4,132,4,128,4,125,13,122,22,114,31,110,34,111,36,116,36,116" href="http://rheinlandpfalz.demo_de/" title="Rheinland-Pfalz" alt="Rheinland-Pfalz" >
<area shape="poly" coords="51,76,55,82,58,88,56,92,54,95,52,94,51,93,44,98,47,101,41,107,35,113,32,108,23,114,17,116,15,118,14,121,10,120,6,117,3,107,7,93,4,85,15,82,16,81,16,78,23,72,30,69,32,70,33,72,34,78,36,79,44,76,42,69,45,68,47,69,51,70,51,76,51,76" href="http://nrw.demo_de/"  title="Nordrhein-Westfalen" alt="Nordrhein-Westfalen" >
<area shape="poly" coords="62,92,60,97,60,98,62,99,64,97,65,96,71,102,66,113,68,118,63,124,56,129,51,129,50,128,50,131,53,139,52,145,49,146,46,144,45,142,43,144,41,143,38,131,33,133,32,131,34,127,36,124,34,120,35,117,36,117,36,114,39,111,43,105,45,103,47,101,45,98,47,95,51,93,52,94,53,95,56,93,58,91,62,92,62,92" href="http://hessen.demo_de/" title="Hessen" alt="Hessen" >
<area shape="poly" coords="84,95,90,97,90,100,91,102,96,105,104,108,106,104,110,107,104,112,105,114,103,116,100,116,98,118,97,121,95,122,91,120,89,119,88,125,81,122,79,127,73,120,70,117,68,115,68,111,72,102,68,99,68,96,79,91,82,92,84,95,84,95" href="http://thueringen.demo_de/" title="Thüringen" alt="Thüringen" >

<area shape="poly" coords="64,140,64,144,66,146,70,146,69,149,72,156,75,163,72,170,69,172,67,175,68,178,70,182,70,192,62,195,57,193,52,189,50,190,52,192,48,193,42,189,38,195,36,193,34,195,27,195,26,187,27,177,31,168,41,151,42,145,45,144,47,145,47,147,49,147,58,140,61,140,64,140,64,140" href="http://bw.demo_de/" title="Baden Württemberg" alt="Baden Württemberg"  >
<area shape="poly" coords="78,124,82,122,87,123,88,119,90,118,92,120,94,122,99,120,105,126,111,135,110,136,109,138,110,140,116,147,119,148,126,155,134,161,134,169,128,169,127,174,124,176,120,178,117,180,120,186,123,193,122,196,119,197,115,195,111,193,98,195,87,201,83,199,79,197,71,202,67,199,63,196,66,192,69,189,69,186,67,175,68,171,71,170,74,162,69,154,68,148,58,139,55,145,51,144,51,128,56,126,61,123,65,119,70,118,73,119,78,124,78,124" href="http://bayern.demo_de/" title="Bayern" alt="Bayern" >
<area shape="poly" coords="132,43,132,46,136,45,132,55,134,59,139,64,139,69,143,77,141,82,142,85,144,88,137,91,134,92,132,95,121,95,117,84,113,81,109,79,104,78,103,75,103,64,103,58,91,53,92,50,94,47,101,45,113,49,117,47,120,45,123,42,126,41,132,43,132,43" href="http://brandenburg.demo_de/" title="Brandenburg" alt="Brandenburg">
</map>

<ul class="list_popular"><li><a href="http://berlin.demo_de">Berlin</a></li><li><a href="http://hamburg.demo_de">Hamburg</a></li><li><a href="http://muenchen.demo_de">München</a></li><li><a href="http://koeln.demo_de">Köln</a></li><li><a href="http://stuttgart.demo_de">Stuttgart</a></li><li><a href="http://dortmund.demo_de">Dortmund</a></li><li><a href="http://essen.demo_de">Essen</a></li><li><a href="http://duesseldorf.demo_de">Düsseldorf</a></li><li><a href="http://bremen.demo_de">Bremen</a></li><li><a href="http://hannover.demo_de">Hannover</a></li></ul>

</div>
&nbsp;<br>


<h2 class="heading">Kostenlose Annoncen</h2>
Kostenlos inserieren und verkaufen im Kleinanzeigen&shy;markt demo. Schnäppchen finden und direkt mit dem Verkäufer in Kontakt treten.
<p>
Täglich aktuelle Kleinanzeigen von privat und gewerblich. Annoncen gratis aufgeben.

</td>
<td width="20"><img src="/g/p/t.gif" width="20" height="1" alt=""></td>
<td align="left" width="322" valign="top">

<!--<h3 style="margin:0"> Kleinanzeigen in </h3>-->
<table width="322" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="161" nowrap>
<span class="listtitle"><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/tiermarkt">Tiermarkt</a>&nbsp;</span>
<ul class="categories">

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/fische" >Fische</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/hasen-nagetiere" >Hasen, Nagetiere</a>&nbsp;</li>

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/hunde" >Hunde, Welpen</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/katzen" >Katzen</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/pferdemarkt" >Pferdemarkt</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/reptilien-terrarien" >Reptilien, Terrarien</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/tiermarkt-sonstige" >Sonstige Tiere</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/voegel" >Vögel</a>&nbsp;</li>

</ul>

<span class="listtitle"><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/marktplatz">Marktplatz</a>&nbsp;</span>
<ul class="categories">

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/antiquitaeten-kunst" >Antiquitäten & Kunst</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/audio-hifi" >Audio & Hi-Fi</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/baby-kindersachen" >Baby & Kindersachen</a>&nbsp;</li>

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/beauty-gesundheit" >Beauty & Gesundheit</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/bekleidung" >Bekleidung</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/buecher" >Bücher & Zeitschriften</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/computer-zubehoer" >Computer & Zubehör</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/eintrittskarten" >Eintrittskarten & Tickets</a>&nbsp;</li>

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/foto-camcorder" >Foto & Camcorder</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/handy-telefon-fax" >Handy, Telefon, Fax</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/haus-garten" >Haus & Garten</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/haushaltsgeraete" >Haushaltsgeräte</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/moebel-hausrat" >Möbel & Hausrat</a>&nbsp;</li>

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/modellbau" >Modellbau</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/musikinstrumente" >Musikinstrumente</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/sammeln" >Sammeln</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/software-spiele" >Software & Spiele</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/sonstiges" >Sonstiges</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/sportsachen" >Sportsachen</a>&nbsp;</li>

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/tv-video" >TV & Video</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/uhren-schmuck" >Uhren & Schmuck</a>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>

<span class="listtitle"><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/dienstleistungen">Dienstleistungen</a>&nbsp;</span>
<ul class="categories">

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/betreuung-pflege" >Betreuung & Pflege</a>&nbsp;</li>

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/bueroarbeiten" >Büroarbeiten</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/finanzen-versicherungen" >Finanzen & Versicherungen</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/handwerkliche-dienstleistungen" >Handwerk</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/haushaltshilfe" >Haushaltshilfe</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/kunst-events" >Kunst & Events</a>&nbsp;</li>

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/sonstige-dienstleistungen" >Sonstige Dienstleistungen</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/umzug-transporte" >Umzug & Transporte</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/unterricht-seminare" >Unterricht & Seminare</a>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</td><td valign="top" width="161" nowrap>
<span class="listtitle"><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/immobilienmarkt">Immobilienmarkt</a>&nbsp;</span>

<ul class="categories">

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/ferienhaeuser" >Ferienhäuser</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/ferienwohnungen" >Ferienwohnungen</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/gewerbeflaeche" >Gewerbefläche</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/grundstuecke" >Grundstücke</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/haueser-kaufen" >Häuser: Kauf</a>&nbsp;</li>

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/haueser-mieten" >Häuser: Miete</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/sonstige-immobilien" >Sonstige Immobilien</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/wohngemeinschaften" >Wohngemeinschaften</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/wohnungen-kaufen" >Wohnungen: Kauf</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/mietwohnungen" >Wohnungen: Miete</a>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>


<span class="listtitle"><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/jobs">Stellenmarkt</a>&nbsp;</span>
<ul class="categories">

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/ausbildungsplaetze" >Ausbildungsplätze</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/minijobs-400-euro" >Minijobs (400 Euro)</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/nebenjobs" >Nebenjobs</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/praktikumsplaetze" >Praktikumsplätze</a>&nbsp;</li>

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/studentenjobs" >Studentenjobs</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/teilzeitstellen" >Teilzeitstellen</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/vollzeitstellen" >Vollzeitstellen</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/weiterbildung" >Weiterbildung</a>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>

<span class="listtitle"><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/fahrzeugmarkt">Fahrzeugmarkt</a>&nbsp;</span>

<ul class="categories">

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/autos" >Autos</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/autoteile" >Autoteile</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/boote" >Boote</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/fahrraeder" >Fahrräder</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/motorraeder" >Motorräder</a>&nbsp;</li>

<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/motorradteile" >Motorradteile</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/motorroller" >Motorroller</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/nutzfahrzeuge" >Nutzfahrzeuge</a>&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_de/kleinanzeigen/wohnwagen-wohnmobile" >Wohnwagen, -mobile</a>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>

<td align="left" width="250" valign="top">
<h2 style="margin:0">Kleinanzeigen Deutschland.</h2><div class="listing_mini_container">
<div class="listing_mini" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#F0ECDB';" style="border-bottom-color:#2A6EE4">
<hr>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/fewo-und-fezi-im-ostseeheilbad-zingst-magdeburg">FeWo und FeZi im Ostseeheilbad Zing.</a><br>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/fewo-und-fezi-im-ostseeheilbad-zingst-magdeburg"><img src="/data/adpix/thumb/fewo-und-fezi-im-ostseeheilbad-zingst-549.jpg" width="60" height="45" border=0 alt=""></a>

<strong>70&euro;</strong> <small> in Magdeburg, Altstadt</small><br>
<p>Bieten im Seeheilbad Zingst an der Ostsee eine F...</p>
</div>

<div class="listing_mini" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#F0ECDB';" style="border-bottom-color:#2A6EE4">
<hr>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/die-zukunft-selbst-in-die-hand-nehmen-saarbruecken">Die Zukunft selbst in die Hand nehm.</a><br>

<a href="/kleinanzeige/die-zukunft-selbst-in-die-hand-nehmen-saarbruecken"><img src="/data/adpix/thumb/die-zukunft-selbst-in-die-hand-nehmen-383376-0.jpg" width="60" height="45" border=0 alt=""></a>
<strong>230.000&euro;</strong> <small> in Saarbrücken</small><br>
<p>Die Zukunft selbst in die Hand nehmen!Dieses, de...</p>
</div>

<div class="listing_mini" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#F0ECDB';" style="border-bottom-color:#2A6EE4">
<hr>

<a href="/kleinanzeige/diese-lage-ist-einzigartig-oy-mittelberg">Diese Lage ist einzigartig!</a><br>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/diese-lage-ist-einzigartig-oy-mittelberg"><img src="/data/adpix/thumb/diese-lage-ist-einzigartig-438066-0.jpg" width="60" height="45" border=0 alt=""></a>
<strong>450.000&euro;</strong> <small> in Oy-Mittelberg</small><br>
<p>Auch bei diesem Bauernhaus finden Sie die typisc...</p>
</div>

<div class="listing_mini" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#F0ECDB';" style="border-bottom-color:#2A6EE4">

<hr>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/angebot-der-woche-sehr-geraeumiges-schmuckstueck-im-rottaler-baederdreieck-mit-schoenem-eingewachsenen-garten--malching">SCHNÄPPCHEN ! Sehr geräumiges SCHMÜ.</a><br>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/angebot-der-woche-sehr-geraeumiges-schmuckstueck-im-rottaler-baederdreieck-mit-schoenem-eingewachsenen-garten--malching"><img src="/data/adpix/thumb/angebot-der-woche-sehr-geraeumiges-schmuckstueck-im-rottaler-baederdreieck-mit-schoenem-eingewachsenen-garten--423148-0.jpg" width="60" height="45" border=0 alt=""></a>
<strong>189.000&euro;</strong> <small> in Malching</small><br>
<p>Dieses schöne ehemalige "Lehrerhaus" ist etwas f...</p>
</div>


<div class="listing_mini" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#F0ECDB';" style="border-bottom-color:#2A6EE4">
<hr>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/2-3-familienhaus-mit-2-einzelgaragen-darmstadt">2-3 Familienhaus mit 2 Einzelgarage.</a><br>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/2-3-familienhaus-mit-2-einzelgaragen-darmstadt"><img src="/data/adpix/thumb/2-3-familienhaus-mit-2-einzelgaragen-416016-0.jpg" width="60" height="45" border=0 alt=""></a>
<strong>425.000&euro;</strong> <small> in Darmstadt, Arheilgen</small><br>
<p>Es handelt sich um eine große Immobilie mit stil...</p>

</div>

<div class="listing_mini" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#F0ECDB';" style="border-bottom-color:#2A6EE4">
<hr>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/ein-bis-zweifamilienhaus-in-zentraler-lage-von-landshut-landshut">Ein bis Zweifamilienhaus in zentral.</a><br>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/ein-bis-zweifamilienhaus-in-zentraler-lage-von-landshut-landshut"><img src="/data/adpix/thumb/ein-bis-zweifamilienhaus-in-zentraler-lage-von-landshut-415409-0.jpg" width="60" height="45" border=0 alt=""></a>
<strong>195.000&euro;</strong> <small> in Landshut, Achdorf</small><br>

<p>Es handelt sich um ein Ein- bis Zweifamilienhaus...</p>
</div>

<div class="listing_mini" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#F0ECDB';" style="border-bottom-color:#2A6EE4">
<hr>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/wohnen-zwischen-kur-und-festspielhaus-baden-baden">Wohnen zwischen Kur- und Festspielh.</a><br>
<a href="/kleinanzeige/wohnen-zwischen-kur-und-festspielhaus-baden-baden"><img src="/data/adpix/thumb/wohnen-zwischen-kur-und-festspielhaus-414142-0.jpg" width="60" height="45" border=0 alt=""></a>
<strong>2.400&euro;</strong> <small> in Baden-Baden</small><br>

<p>Wohnen zwischen Kur- und FestspielhausIn zentral...</p>
</div>
</div>  
<p>
<img src="/g/p/FX_BN_wohnung_gedemot.gif" width="250" height="250" alt="Kleinanzeigen Immobilien">
</td>


</tr>
</table>


</div>
<div class="footer">
<ul style="margin-bottom:5px;">
<!-- <li><a href="/seiten/werben.htm" rel="nofollow">Werbung</a></li>-->        
<li><a href="/seiten/ueberuns.htm" rel="nofollow">&Uuml;ber uns</a></li>
<li><a href="/seiten/jobs.htm" rel="nofollow">Jobs &amp; Karriere</a></li>
<li><a href="/presse/">Presse</a></li>  
<li><a href="/hilfe/demo_kontaktieren.htm" rel="nofollow">Kontakt</a></li>

<li><a href="/seiten/impressum.htm" rel="nofollow">Impressum</a></li>
<li><a href="/seiten/datenschutz.htm" rel="nofollow">Datenschutz</a></li>
<li><a href="/seiten/nutzungsbedingungen.htm" rel="nofollow">AGB</a></li>
<li><a href="/hilfe/">Hilfe</a></li>
<li><a href="/seiten/sicher-handeln.htm" rel="nofollow">Sicherheit</a></li>     
<li><a href="/seiten/weitersagen.htm" title="Berichten Sie Ihren Freunden von demo!" rel="nofollow">Weitersagen</a></li>

<li><a href="/beliebte-suchbegriffe/">Beliebte Suchen</a></li>
<li><a href="/subapp_rss/new-classifieds.xml"><span class="sprites-1 sprite-rss2" style="position:relative;top:2px;"></span></a></li>           
</ul>

<ul style="margin-bottom:5px;">
<li>Andere L&auml;nder:</li>
<li><a href="http://snake.demo_ch">Schweiz</a></li><li><a href="http://snake.demo_at">&Ouml;sterreich</a></li><li><a href="http://snake.demo_es">Spanien</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>  
<script src="/app_global/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/app_global/header.min.js?1307361841" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/app_global/jquery.maphilight.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$.fn.maphilight.defaults = {
fill: true,
fillColor: 'FF6B02',
fillOpacity: 0.4,
stroke: true,
strokeColor: 'FF6B02',
strokeOpacity: 1,
strokeWidth: 1,
fade: true,
alwaysOn: false,
neverOn: false,
groupBy: false
}
$('.map').maphilight();
});</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there an external resource that's loading slowly (like an image)? Could you provide a link to the page?

Comment: There is no external image loaded. All coming from the same internal developent server (apache 2.x). Unfortunatelly the page is in development and therefore I can't provide a link. 

The page is loading JS, but at the very bottom of the page. just before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

DOM Content Loaded is fired when the DOM is ready - parsed and loaded.  The onload event is fired only when all the assets have been downloaded including images and CSS.

Comment: I know, but as the chart indicates all the content has been loaded already way before. The timeline should show all the content that has to be downloaded - at least I hope so.